# AskUbuntu Add-on for Firefox, Opera and Chrome

Tags: app, firefox, google-chrome, askubuntu

### Screenshots

Firefox

[image: Firefox]

Opera

[image: Opera]

Chrome

[image: Chrome]

### About

The extension, called [AskUbuntu Add-on](http://www.webgapps.org/addons/askubuntu), allows to easily track user info and questions from askubuntu.com.

This extension displays user reputation and badges in the toolbar, provides an easy access menu to unanswered questions , user questions, favorites and user tags. It has an update checker that alerts when there is new activity in the user account or unanswered questions. The configuration options allow to disable alerts, limit the number of items displayed in the menu, hide user info and control the frequency of updates. There is also an option to store data temporarily if the browser is on private mode.

#### License

Free, open source released under:

[GNU General Public License v3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) [Firefox]

[Apache License, Version 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html) [Opera and Chrome]

#### Download

Home page: [http://www.webgapps.org/addons/askubuntu](http://askubuntu-extension.blogspot.com)

GitHub downloads: http://github.com/webgapps/askubuntu/downloads

Mozilla gallery: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/242568/

Opera gallery: [https://addons.opera.com/addons/extensions/details/askubuntu-add-on...](https://addons.opera.com/addons/extensions/details/askubuntu-add-on/?display=en)

Google gallery: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hamgohmiimamjpabgncmklojoibjknon

#### Platform

Firefox 3.5 to 4.0b8pre

Opera 11.0

Chrome 5.0.316.0

[OS independent]

### Contact

Developed by [lovinglinux](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/user/4352153/)

### Code

Javascript, HTML (Opera and Chrome) and XUL (Firefox)

Source code at http://github.com/webgapps/askubuntu

> **Note:** some Gnome users might experience diminished functionality if their
> Firefox does not show icons in menus,
> since the icons are indicators of new
> activity. To solve this problem visit:
> https://askubuntu.com/questions/8586/where-is-the-gnome-option-to-display-icons-in-menus

Comment: AskUbuntu Add-on 1.0.1 was released today and is available for download. This version brings several new features - http://askubuntu-extension.blogspot.com/2010/10/askubuntu-add-on-101-released.html

Comment: @lovinglinux Thank you very much. I'm a fan of your add-on.

Comment: Have you considered making this work with any site in the network?

Comment: I have considered making a version for other sites, but right now I'm focusing on improving the extension and making versions for Opera and Chrome.

Comment: I just received an e-mail stating that the extension has been approved by Mozilla, so no more account required to download and updates will be served with extensions updates :)

Comment: The first Opera version has been released!

Comment: @loving: Hooray! (Might we see a Chrome extension? :)

Comment: @george-edison Yes! A version for Chrome is next in the queue. ;)

Comment: @george-edison The Chrome version is almost done :)

Comment: The Opera version has been approved by Opera and is available for download at https://addons.labs.opera.com/addons/extensions/details/askubuntu-add-on/1.0.0/?display=en

Comment: Chrome version released! Also released a new version for Opera with a few improvements.

Comment: Needs some updating. Do you still work on it?

Comment: I haven't worked on the Chrome and Opera versions, but I recently released a new version for Firefox. However, I do not see a reason to put too much effort on this, since it has less than 200 users. I will keep updating compatibility and fixing bugs when I have available time.

Comment: What happened to this app?